# Is it impossible to find a rule for every Nth sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was relearning some sequences and series, and as I was going through the problem sets I decided to find the $N$th rule for every sequence given. I got to a specific sequence that after about $2$ hours of trying I gave up and concluded that it may be impossible. Am I correct? The sequence was given as the recurrence relation:

$$a_{n+1} = 3a_n - 12,\quad a_1 = 10$$

The book just wishes you to find up to four terms and finish which is simple however finding the $N$th term turned out to be more difficult then expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Hint*: $$a_{n+1}-6=3(a_n - 6) $$

Comment: Thats much simpler thank you!

Answer (score 0):

$$a(n) = 3^{n-1}\cdot 10 - 12 \cdot \sum_{i=0}^{n-2} 3^i$$ for $n\geq 2$

The summation is a geometric series and so has a nice closed form as well; I leave it to you to compute it.

Comment: Thanks, I just was overthinking things, however is the general assumption that not every sequence can possibly be described by a function of N?

Comment: @chris360 A sequence is *by definition* a function of $N$. It may not permit a simple expression in terms of a preselected set of elementary functions and operations ...

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen, thank you for the correction in my terminology and your answer!